# GAE push-to-deploy returning internal server error

Tags: google-app-engine

I've set up push-to-deploy for my application and the auth seems to work fine, but now I get this when I push:

```
Counting objects: 463, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (393/393), done.
Writing objects: 100% (397/397), 1.70 MiB | 105 KiB/s, done.
Total 397 (delta 295), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Scanning pack: 100% (397/397), done.
remote: Storing objects: 100% (397/397), done.
remote: Processing commits: 100% (58/58), done.
remote: Starting execution...
remote: Created deployment: sjf-nw.clouddev.gaeTemplate-d981b975f1ecaa6d.deployment_1383853857059
remote: Created deployment: sjf-nw.clouddev.gaeTemplate-d981b975f1ecaa6d.deployment_1383853857059
remote: Created deployment: sjf-nw.clouddev.gaeTemplate-d981b975f1ecaa6d.deployment_1383853857059
remote: Error: internal server error
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: recursion detected in die handler
Everything up-to-date
```

Does anyone know if this is an error on GAE's side or something I could fix?  I haven't been able to find anything about similar error messages.

Comment: It's a preview release so it could break at any time. Suggest you switch back to old style deployments.